# Creating inputs that make a subtraction-based GCD algorithm slow

Tags: algorithms, gcd-and-lcm

I have a GCD algorithm that is based on comparison and subtraction. The principle looks like this:

```
while a != b
    while (a > b)
        n = 1
        while (a > pow(b, n))
            a = a - pow(b, n)
            n = n + 1
    swap a with b
```

I want to specifically find some numbers that makes the algorithm slow (number of loops run). For example, $5$ and $15$ makes the algorithm very fast, while $2^{15}$ and $1$ makes it slow, but $2^{15}-1$ and $2^{13}-1$ makes it even slower. However, randomly-generated numbers like $30533$ and $19015$ can be slowest, among what numbers I have now.

Is there an algorithm that can find (or better, calculate) a pair of number that makes the above GCD algorithm slow, with both numbers under a given cap. In my case, I need the numbers to be smaller than (not equal to) $2^{15}$ (or $32768$).

Enumerating is not an option for me because profiling the algorithm in my environment is very slow, also if the cap gets bigger, enumerating is impractical.

Comment: I get loop count $32767$ for $\gcd(2^{15},1)$ and $2736$ for $\gcd(2^{15}-1,2^{13}-1)$. What do you get?

Comment: @Somos Sorry, I changed the actual algorithm when I kept working. I updated the question

Comment: Copying what's currently in your post directly into Python has $\gcd(2^{15}, 1)$ at 32767 and $\gcd(2^{15} - 1, 2^{13} - 1)$ at 42.

Comment: In fact $\gcd(2^{15}, 1)$ is fairly easily seen to be (approximately) slowest. As long as one of the numbers is not one, the total $a + b$ drops with at least 2 every loop, for a total of at most $2^{15}$ steps, which you already achieve with $2^{15}, 1$.